# How can I place an ASP.NET menu control into cache?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, menu

I have a SharePoint2010 site that I have created an ASP.NET menu control for.
The ASP.NET menu's content is initially empty, and on Page_Load I load its content from standard HTML files on the server:

```
           protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string MenuPath = (string)ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["RootMenuPath"].ToString();

            Menu1.Items[0].ChildItems[0].Text = File.ReadAllText(MenuPath + "\\About.htm");
//etc...
}
```

I notice this is a horrible way to do things.  It hits the disk every single time a user loads a page.

How can I either:

a) Cache the code and asp.net menu item so that it stays in memory?

b) Use another method to ensure it isn't loaded from the disk?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap data load into property and use at least page Cache there:

```
 readonly object cacheLock = new object();
string AboutHTM
{
    get
    {
        if (Cache.Get("page.about") == null)
            lock (cacheLock)
            {
                if (Cache.Get("page.about") == null)
                    Cache.Insert(File.ReadAllText(MenuPath + "\\About.htm"));
            }
        return Cache["page.about"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed use the cache or some variable that is initialized only once in `Application_Start` and reused later but I am afraid that you are doing some premature optimization here. You probably shouldn't be doing it unless you have identified that this is a bottleneck for your application performance. Reading files from disk is a fast operation especially if they are small.

Comment: ya, we had issue with page loads being slow, and it was pointing to the menu as the culprit already.

Comment: @Kolten, I see. Try caching then to see if this will solve your performance problems.

Comment: Add Trace.Warn() before and after statement and enable the Trace option of the Page.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would store the menu data in an XML file, and cache the XML file.

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

if (Cache.Get("MenuData") == null)
{
    xDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("/MenuData.xml"));
    Cache.Insert("SiteNav", xDoc, new CacheDependency(Server.MapPath("/MenuData.xml")));
}
else
{
    xDoc = (XmlDocument)HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("MenuData");
}
```